# Issue with Clipboard Pasting in Safari on Mac using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, python, macos, selenium-webdriver, safari

I am currently working on automating tests for a web application, and I've encountered an issue with clipboard pasting using Selenium WebDriver. The scenario involves a copy button that, when clicked, copies text to the clipboard.And what I need is to check if the copied text is correct and I don't want to use the external modules for the same. I've implemented a solution that works well on Windows Chrome and MacOS Chrome, but I'm facing difficulties with MacOS Safari.

I've implemented a JavaScript-based solution to retrieve copied text from the clipboard. The code, outlined in the original post, successfully works on Windows Chrome and Mac Chrome. However, when tested on Mac Safari, the clipboard pasting does not function as intended. I suspect that there might be browser-specific nuances or differences in implementation between Chrome and Safari.

```py
def retrieve_copied_text(self):
    """ 
    Retrieve the copied text from the clipboard using JavaScript.
    """
    script = """
    var textarea = document.createElement('div');
    textarea.contentEditable = true;
    textarea.id = 'myTextarea';  
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
    textarea.focus();
    return textarea;
    """
    textarea = self.driver.execute_script(script)
    target_element = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'myTextarea')
    actions = webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver)
    cmd_ctrl = Keys.COMMAND if platform.system().lower() == 'darwin' else Keys.CONTROL
    actions.move_to_element(target_element).click(target_element).key_down(cmd_ctrl).key_down("v").key_up("v").key_up(cmd_ctrl).perform()
    pasted_content = target_element.text
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].remove();", textarea)
    return pasted_content
```

Has anyone faced a similar problem with clipboard pasting in Safari on Mac using Selenium WebDriver? If so, could you please provide insights or a solution to make this work consistently across different browsers and operating systems? I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: usually easier to just send keys to the element.  i.e.: target_element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')